# Can you please help me correct this valueerror: math domain error?

Tags: numpy, math, logistic-regression

I'm trying to calculate the loss function in Logistic Regression but end up getting a math error in it. can you please help me rectify this error?

```
def loss(y,a):
    L = (-y*math.log(a)-(1-y)*math.log(1-a)).mean()
    return L
```

Comment: Check `log()` argument. Domain error: argument is negative, `errno` is set to `EDOM`.

Comment: Yes, i get it. The instructor allowed us to try hardcoding this part( either clipping the input function or by setting an ephsilon term) to negate this instance. can you help me code this part ?

Comment: @vishwa if you feel that the below answer is appropriate, kindly mark it as a verified answer so that it helps others who might visit this question later.

Comment: @Parthasarathy, I did, but its not showing up because of my lesser reputation score.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the error because you are trying to find the log of a negative number (i.e. `a` is becoming negative). From your equation, I infer `y` is the true value and `a` is the predicted value. And the predictions come for the eqution below:

[image: enter link description here]

So there is no way `a` can be negative, so kindly check your prediction function definition.